# How can I set up a Drupal rules action to play a specific sound?

Tags: rules, files

I would like set a sound alert as a Drupal rules action- for Drupal to play a specific sound file eg in audiofield. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would redirect to the node with the audiofield and set it to autoplay. This way you can have only one audio field per node of course.

Comment: Thank you Maarten, that should solve this. I wonder if ideally there is any way to do it without the 'page redirect' on rules, so the user can stay on the same page.